# algorithm for number of subsequences containing at most k numbers with no element repeated in each of the subsequence

Tags: combinatorics

For e.g if the array is 2,2,3,3,5 and k=3
there are total 18 subequences
1 subequence of length 0(i.e empty subsequence)
5 subsequences of length 1

8 subsequences with length 2

4 subsequences with length 3

how to proceed?

Comment: It's better if you spent more time trying to solve your questions before posting them here.

Comment: i did spend 4 days on this one and what i observed is that i could use binomial coefficients to solve this one but only some of my test cases are getting passed....so i thought maybe someone could give me a better approach

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this using dynamic programming. Let me show instead the solution using generating functions, which can also be implemented using dynamic programming.

Suppose that there are $m$ distinct values in the array, appearing $n_1,\ldots,n_m$ times. The generating function
$$ \prod_{i=1}^m (1+n_ix) $$
counts the number of subsequences with distinct values of size $k$, in the sense that this is the coefficient of $x^k$. For example, in your case $m = 3$ and $n_1=n_2=2,n_3=1$. Therefore the generating function is
$$
(1+2x)^2(1+x) = 
(1+4x+4x^2)(1+x) =
1+5x+8x^2+4x^3.
$$

Comment: Yes,thankyou...i too had the same approach but slightly wrong...now i'll try to code it